# InfiiniteWP and WP Networks (multisite)

Tags: multisite, admin

We have two servers. One that has individual, stand-alone WP installs. The second server has an instance of WP multisite (networks). We're looking to combine these two platforms on a new, beefier VM and are evaluating management tools.

So far we've tested [InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/) (IWP) on the first box with the stand alone sites and have been pleased. However, my team has questions on how IWP will impact Networks.

Has anyone experience on using IWP (or a similar management tool) on a server with both standalone and instances of networks? If IWP is not the tool, is there another option to be able to manage both Networks and an army of stand-alones co-habiting on the same LAMP stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I think I figured this out. I wanted to leave my findings here with the hope that others can correct anything I may have erred on or findings I have misinterpreted.*

**Testing Method:** I set up a new [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) install with a lamp stack (`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`). I first set up [wp_cli](http://wp-cli.org/) -- the commandline tool akin to [drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) -- which sped along the download and set up of WP, [converted](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-using-multisite) it to a multisite install, and created two sub-blogs. From various post read, Mutlisite is happiest in the root folder of apache. Though this can be chanced with modifications to mod_rewrite rules.

After multisite was up and working with two sub blogs, I installed [IWP](http://infinitewp.com) to it's own folder (var/www/iwp) directly under root. I activated iwp-client under each individual sub-blog and the master blog.

Though you can connect the sub-blogs, IWP really only interacts with the main blog. The two sub blogs won't show updates and can't be individually backed up. Though backing up the main blog appears to copy the entire WP file tree and database.

To test updates, I copied a number of plug-ins and themes from web5 and placed the folders on the vagrant box, activated them in the Networks admin panel, took a back up in IWP, and then issued an update all command. All updates appeared successful. I then restored the previous backup, which showed

**Findings/Caveats:**

- WP mutli was set up as subfolder, not subdomain mode.
- IWP backs up to a hard-to-find, yet apache visible folder. Would this
  be a security risk?

**Results:** Yes, IWP can nicely interact with the *main blog* of the Networks/Multisite install.

**Next steps**: I'd be continuing to test to see if I can have a larger, beefier VM that can host an array of both stand alone and perhaps an install or two of Multisite. Would IWP be the tool of choice to manage *all* installs on the server, or is it best to leave multisite to manage itself and let IWP manage the stand-alones.